# What are some opportunities improve performance / concurrency in the following Scala + Akka code?

Tags: scala, concurrency, immutability, akka, par

I am looking for opportunities to increase concurrency and performance in my Scala 2.9 / Akka 2.0 RC2 code.  Given the following code:

```
import akka.actor._

case class DataDelivery(data:Double)

class ComputeActor extends Actor {
    var buffer = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Double]()

    val functionsToCompute = List("f1","f2","f3","f4","f5")
    var functionMap = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,(Map[String,Any]) => Double]()  
    functionMap += {"f1" -> f1}
    functionMap += {"f2" -> f2}
    functionMap += {"f3" -> f3}
    functionMap += {"f4" -> f4}
    functionMap += {"f5" -> f5}

    def updateData(data:Double):scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Double] = {
        buffer += data
        buffer
    }

    def f1(map:Map[String,Any]):Double = {
//    println("hello from f1")
      0.0
    }

    def f2(map:Map[String,Any]):Double = {
//    println("hello from f2")
      0.0
    }

    def f3(map:Map[String,Any]):Double = {
//    println("hello from f3")
      0.0
    }

    def f4(map:Map[String,Any]):Double = {
//    println("hello from f4")
      0.0
    }

    def f5(map:Map[String,Any]):Double = {
//    println("hello from f5")
      0.0
    }

    def computeValues(immutableBuffer:IndexedSeq[Double]):Map[String,Double] = {
        var map = Map[String,Double]()
        try {
            functionsToCompute.foreach(function => {
                val value = functionMap(function)
                function match {
                    case "f1" =>
                        var v = value(Map("lookback"->10,"buffer"->immutableBuffer,"parm1"->0.0))
                        map += {function -> v}
                    case "f2" =>
                        var v = value(Map("lookback"->20,"buffer"->immutableBuffer))
                        map += {function -> v}
                    case "f3" =>
                        var v = value(Map("lookback"->30,"buffer"->immutableBuffer,"parm1"->1.0,"parm2"->false))
                        map += {function -> v}
                    case "f4" =>
                        var v = value(Map("lookback"->40,"buffer"->immutableBuffer))
                        map += {function -> v}
                    case "f5" =>
                        var v = value(Map("buffer"->immutableBuffer))
                        map += {function -> v}
                    case _ => 
                        println(this.unhandled())
                }
            })
        } catch {
            case ex: Exception =>
              ex.printStackTrace()
        }
        map
    }

    def receive = {
      case DataDelivery(data) =>
        val startTime = System.nanoTime()/1000
        val answers = computeValues(updateData(data))
        val endTime = System.nanoTime()/1000
        val elapsedTime = endTime - startTime
        println("elapsed time is " + elapsedTime)
        // reply or forward
      case msg =>
        println("msg is " + msg)
    }

}

object Test {
    def main(args:Array[String]) {
        val system = ActorSystem("actorSystem") 
        val computeActor = system.actorOf(Props(new ComputeActor),"computeActor")
        var i = 0
        while (i < 1000) {  
            computeActor ! DataDelivery(i.toDouble)
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this the output (converted to microseconds) is

```
elapsed time is 4898
elapsed time is 184
elapsed time is 144
    .
    .
    .
elapsed time is 109
elapsed time is 103
```

You can see the JVM's incremental compiler kicking in.

I thought that one quick win might be to change

```
    functionsToCompute.foreach(function => {
```

to

```
    functionsToCompute.par.foreach(function => {
```

but this results in the following elapsed times

```
elapsed time is 31689
elapsed time is 4874
elapsed time is 622
    .
    .
    .
elapsed time is 698
elapsed time is 2171
```

**Some info:**

1) I'm running this on a Macbook Pro with 2 cores.

2) In the full version, the functions are long running operations that loop over portions of the mutable shared buffer.  This doesn't appear to be a problem since retrieving messages from the actor's mailbox is controlling the flow, but I suspect it could be an issue with increased concurrency.  This is why I've converted to an IndexedSeq.

3) In the full version, the functionsToCompute list may vary, so that not all items in the functionMap are necessarily called (i.e.) functionMap.size may be much larger than functionsToCompute.size

4) The functions can be computed in parallel, but the resultant map must be complete before returning

**Some questions:**

1) What can I do to make the parallel version run faster?

2) Where would it make sense to add non-blocking and blocking futures?

3) Where would it make sense to forward computation to another actor?

4) What are some opportunities for increasing immutability/safety?

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with your answers... but it's point 4 that's the interesting one for me.  It looks like you can make good use of akka.dispatch.Future.sequence here.  Create a list of Futures that are doing the computation and use sequence to turn that into a Future on the list of results. When that future returns, fold the results into the aggregate map/list/container you need.

Comment: @DerekWyatt.  In the full version, the answers are passed on to another actor.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Why not have one actor for each function?

Comment: @ViktorKlang.  I guess that would be possible, but I need to collect the results of all of the function evaluations in a single map that will be passed on to another actor.  Wouldn't the fork-join functionality of Futures be ideal for this?  Unfortunately, I don't have enough experience with Futures yet, and I'm not clear on how your suggestion would be set up with this requirement in mind.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ViktorKlang.  I guess I need to spend some time reading the Akka 2.0 documentation for composing Futures...

Comment: Futures really are your "go to" solution here, I think.  For fun, I tried to model Matrix Multiplication with Actors and it was /hell/.  For straight, raw computation, Futures are just better in general.

Comment: Yup, Futures are great for computation.

Comment: @DerekWyatt.  Might you be able to provide an example of what you suggested in your first comment?

Comment: @ViktorKlang.  Hi Viktor.  I can't seem to get any of the code in the Akka 2.0 examples for Futures to a compilable form.  Is there anywhere I can go to see a complete example of using Futures with Akka 2.0 (including all imports, setup, etc..)?

Comment: Bruce: Unfortunately you're not providing any kind of helpful information for me to help you diagnose your problem. I'm sure hoping that the Akka docs for Futures compiles, because they are compiled before they're mechanically added to the docs. Have you've downloaded the akka distribution from akka.io?

Comment: @ViktorKlang.  Yes, I've downloaded the akka dist from akka.io.  I have no doubt that they compile if you know what you're doing.  The issue is that I cut and paste the code from the docs, and I was getting errors such as not enough arguments for method ask: (implicit timeout: akka.util.Timeout)akka.dispatch.Future[Any]. Unspecified value parameter timeout. I was able to go up the page and find the TimeOut import and implicit value for timeout.  After that, I didn't know what to do with ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(yourExecutorServiceGoesHere).  DerekWyatt provided some example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing an example, as requested (sorry about the delay... I don't have notifications on for SO).

There's a great example in the Akka documentation [Section on 'Composing Futures'](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/futures.html#composing-futures) but I'll give you something a little more tailored to your situation.

Now, after reading this, please take some time to read through the tutorials and docs on Akka's website.  You're missing a lot of key information that those docs will provide for you.

```
import akka.dispatch.{Await, Future, ExecutionContext}
import akka.util.duration._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

object Main {
  // This just makes the example work.  You probably have enough context
  // set up already to not need these next two lines
  val pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(pool)

  // I'm simulating your function.  It just has to return a tuple, I believe
  // with a String and a Double
  def theFunction(s: String, d: Double) = (s, d)
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Here we run your functions - I'm just doing a thousand of them
    // for fun.  You do what yo need to do
    val listOfFutures = (1 to 1000) map { i =>
      // Run them in parallel in the future
      Future {
        theFunction(i.toString, i.toDouble)
      }
    }
    // These lines can be composed better, but breaking them up should
    // be more illustrative.
    //
    // Turn the list of Futures (i.e. Seq[Future[(String, Double)]]) into a
    // Future with a sequence of results (i.e. Future[Seq[(String, Double)]])
    val futureOfResults = Future.sequence(listOfFutures)

    // Convert that future into another future that contains a map instead
    // instead of a sequence
    val intermediate = futureOfResults map { _.toList.toMap }

    // Wait for it complete.  Ideally you don't do this.  Continue to
    // transform the future into other forms or use pipeTo() to get it to go
    // as a result to some other Actor.  "Await" is really just evil... the
    // only place you should really use it is in silly programs like this or
    // some other special purpose app.
    val resultingMap = Await.result(intermediate, 1 second)
    println(resultingMap)

    // Again, just to make the example work
    pool.shutdown()
  }
}
```

All you need in your classpath to get this running is the `akka-actor` jar.  The Akka website will tell you how to set up what you need, but it's really dead simple.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help.  This is great, and addresses the majority of my questions.

Comment: This is pretty cool stuff.  I swapped out the Await with onComplete, and it worked nicely.  I'll try pipeTo() next.

Comment: If I want to compose a future that is a combination of two intermediate futures prior to calling pipeTo(), would I just do something like the following?       val combined = Future {Map("key1"->intermediate, "key2" -> intermediate2)}

Comment: SO isn't the place for this any more... head to the Akka mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user